# Delay when updating ios ui elements from Afnetwork blocks

Tags: ios, block, afnetworking

In my app when the user presses a button I start a HTTP asynchronous request (using AFURLConnectionOperation) and change the text of UILabel in the completionHandler block. This change, however, does not take place when the request is concluded and instead happens around 2-3 seconds later. Below is a code snippet that results in this behavior.

```
    AFURLConnectionOperation* operation = ...
    [opration setCompletionBlock:^{
         NSLog(@"This text appears immediatly");
         [myLabel setText:@"this one is delayed for 2-3 sec"];
    }];
    [opreation start];
```

tahnks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is symptomatic of attempts to try to perform UI updates from background queue. Your problem will be resolved if you add that UI update back to the main queue:

```
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
     NSLog(@"This text appears immediately");
     [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
         [myLabel setText:@"this should not be delayed for 2-3 sec"];
     }];
}];
```

As the `NSOperation` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW36) for `setCompletionBlock` says, you have no assurances of what thread the completion operation will take place:

> The exact execution context for your completion block is not guaranteed but is typically a secondary thread. Therefore, you should not use this block to do any work that requires a very specific execution context. Instead, you should shunt that work to your application’s main thread or to the specific thread that is capable of doing it. ...

UI updates must take place on the main queue, so if your completion block wants to perform UI updates, it must explicitly add them to the main queue.

Comment: You sir deserve more like :-)

Answer (score 2):

`AFURLConnectionOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation`.

Further, by looking at `AFURLConnectionOperation.m`, we can see that `setCompletionBlock:` basically just calls its super method (of course, it also takes care of `locking` and nicely setting the `completionBlock` property as `nil` for you when done).

**Important note**: `AFURLConnectionOperation` does NOT perform the `completionBlock` on the main thread for you. `NSOperation` is also not guaranteed to perform the `completionBlock` on the main thread either.

However, user interface (UI) updates **must** happen on the main thread (otherwise, unexpected things may happen).

To fix this, you need to make sure your UI updates are happening on the main thread. In example, you could do something like this:

```
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"This text appears immediately");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // do your UI updates here...
    });
}];
```